# Prove that a sequence converges iff any open ball around the limit point contains all but finitely many terms of $(x_n)$

Tags: real-analysis

$Let\ (x_n) \subset S\ and\ x \in S.\ Show\ that\ x_n \to x\ iff\ for\ all\ \epsilon>0, the\ open\ ball\ B(\epsilon;x) \ contains \ all\ but\ finitely\ many\ terms\ of\ x_n$

Exercise 3.1.8 of John Stachurski Economic Dynamics

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\epsilon>0$ be arbitrary.

The open ball $B(\epsilon;x)$ contains all but finitely many terms. So for some big $N \in \mathbb{N}$ the points of the sequence not inside this ball come from among $x_1,x_2,x_3,...,x_N$. So

$$ n \geq N+1  \quad\Rightarrow  \quad x_n \in B(\epsilon;x).$$

We have checked that the definition of convergence holds.